# R library/package to count cars in distorted images

Tags: python, image-processing, data-analysis, image-recognition, r

I have a image recognition task, I have one million pictures and I have to detect how many cars are there in each picture. I'm a middle level R user, a beginer python user, and a midle Java user. Which library "software" its my best option (quality results/ time to develop) to achieve this task?

This is an example of the image I have to analyse:

[image]